# Scale Background Image Height Based on Width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a section with a background image with the width of the entirety of the page, and the height scaled based on the width.

I tried setting `background-size: cover`, but that didn't make any difference — the height of the background image stayed as the height of the content of the section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set contain, cover and percent height

```
.backgroundCover {
      background-image: url(http://www.messletters.info/animated-backgrounds/71animatedbg.gif);
        background-size: cover;
}

.backgroundContain {
      background-image: url(http://www.messletters.info/animated-backgrounds/71animatedbg.gif);
        background-size: contain;
}
.backgroundPercents{
   background-image: url(http://www.messletters.info/animated-backgrounds/71animatedbg.gif);
        background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psinetron/8sNwN/1/)

Comment: See, the problem with this is that the div with the background image already has a height set in pixels. I want the height of the image to scale proportionally based on the width.

Comment: In this situation you need to use `img` tag into your block as background

Comment: I add [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psinetron/8sNwN/4/) You can use this technology

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at `background-size: contain;`

To quote W3schools, [contain](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) achieves the following:

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

Comment: When I try to use "contain," it scales both the height and width of the image to the size of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use *contain*

```
background-size: contain;
```

This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fX5E8/.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 500px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/500x200/cccccc&text=Howdy)
                no-repeat
                0% 0%/100%;
}
```